# JWT with multiple domain

Tags: cookies, jwt

Lets say domainA.com creates the JWT for the client.

domainA.com wants the tokens he creates can be used on domainB.com

How is it possible? I think it is related to headers and CORS.

**By default** if domainA creates a token and it is saved in cookies, then this cookie will be sent only to domainA and to nothing elsewhere , right?

So I think when domainA creates the cookie with Set-Cookie, then it needs to specify a list in the same response header, where this cookie can be used on. For example:  domainB and domainC.

Comment: A JWT itself isn't attached to a specific domain. Your questions seems to be more about cookies that JWTs. A cookie is associated to a domain (e.g. `example.com`, if say `https://example.com` set the cookie) and browsers will, by default, send you to that domain only. Optionally, you can set the cookie with a `Domain` attribute (e.g. `Domain=example.com`), which will instruct the browser to also attach the cookies to subdomains of the `Domain` value (e.g. `foo.example.com`, `bar.foo.example.com`, etc.).

Comment: @jub0bs Thank you . What is the situation when example.com want to instruct the browser to attach the cookie to domainB.com ? So not for subdomain , but for another domain?

Comment: That is not possible. That's not how cookies work. For more info, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/